# Fedora: Command not found with sudo

Tags: fedora, sudo, homebrew, brew

I am aware of the --preserve-env or -E flag in `sudo`, however, it seems like this flag causes sudo to act weird in Fedora.

I installed `ranger` with `LinuxBrew`, Here's what I get when I type in `which ranger` as a non-root user:

```bsh
$ which ranger
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ranger
```

And if I sudo,

```bsh
$ sudo -E which ranger
which: no ranger in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin)

$ sudo -E echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/share/Modules/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/david/bin:/home/david/.gem/ruby/2.6.0:/home/david/prog/flutter/bin:/home/david/go/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/david/.local/bin:/snap/bin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/home/david/.gem/ruby/2.6.0:/home/david/go/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/david/.local/bin:/snap/bin:/home/david/prog/flutter/bin

$ sudo -E ranger
sudo: ranger: command not found
```

But things get weirder:

```bsh
sudo --preserve-env=PATH which ranger
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ranger

$ sudo --preserve-env=PATH ranger
sudo: ranger: command not found
```

Can anyone explain what the actual heck is going on here?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a security feature of sudo. In your `/etc/sudoers` file, you should have a line such as :

```
Defaults secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

The meaning of the `secure_path` option is given in the man page of `sudoers`:

> **secure_path :** Path used for every command run from sudo.  If you don't trust the people running sudo to have a sane PATH environment variable you may want to use this.  Another use is if you want to have the “root path” be separate from the “user path”.  Users in the group specified by the exempt_group option are not affected by secure_path.  This option is not set by default.

If you want to avoid this behavior you can define the `exempt_group` option in `/etc/sudoers` with your user inside it. Such as:

```
Defaults exempt_group+=jo
```

On some old RHEL distibutions, you have to create a system group for this: see https://access.redhat.com/solutions/150783